# Further customisation of DialogFragment i.e. title typeface, font, DialogFragment divider color

Tags: android

I'm looking to further customise my DialogFragment particularly I'm looking to change the Typeface and font color of my DialogFragment title. Also I would like to customise divider/blue line between the title and rest of the DialogFragment.

So far I've successfully used the onCreateView to build a custom layout for the main content that goes into the DialogFragment. My DialogFragment can be seen below with the XML further down.

Any ideas as to how I can perform the above-mentioned customisation?

DialogFragment code:

```
public class DialogFragmentFincCalctrInfo extends DialogFragment {

public String TAG = "DialogFragmentFincCalctrInfo";
public MainActivity mainActivity;
public Display display;
public Typeface officialBoldFont, officialRegularFont;
public TextView tvFincCalctrInfo, tvDialogFragmentFincCalctrInfoTitle;

//!< FincCalctr fragment constructor
public DialogFragmentFincCalctrInfo () {

}

//!< FincCalctr fragment constructor
public DialogFragmentFincCalctrInfo(MainActivity _mainActivity, Display _display) {
    mainActivity = _mainActivity;
    display = _display;
}

//!< Inflate and customise the fragment
@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {

    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

    getDialog().setTitle(R.string.finc_calc_info_heading);

    officialRegularFont = Typeface.createFromAsset(getActivity().getAssets(), "square721extendedreg.ttf"); 
    officialBoldFont = Typeface.createFromAsset(getActivity().getAssets(), "square721extendedbold.ttf"); 

    Log.w(TAG, "- - - Main RL - - -");

    View rlMain = inflater.inflate(R.layout.dialog_fragment_layout_finccalctr_info, container, false);

    // 
    tvFincCalctrInfo = (TextView) rlMain.findViewById(R.id.tv_finccalctr_info);

    tvFincCalctrInfo.setTextSize(14.5f);
    tvFincCalctrInfo.setTypeface(officialRegularFont);
    tvFincCalctrInfo.setText(R.string.finc_calc_info_bullet_points_first_pgraph);       
    tvFincCalctrInfo.setGravity(Gravity.CENTER_VERTICAL);
    tvFincCalctrInfo.setTextColor(Color.parseColor("#000000"));

    return rlMain;
}
```

}

XML code:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:padding="10dp"
    android:orientation="vertical">

    <ScrollView
       android:id="@+id/sv_finccalctr_infolayout"
       android:layout_width="fill_parent"
       android:layout_height="wrap_content">

        <LinearLayout android:id="@+id/ll_sv_finccalctr_infolayout"
               android:orientation="vertical"
               android:layout_width="fill_parent"
               android:layout_height="wrap_content">    

                <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/tv_finccalctr_info"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"/>

        </LinearLayout>

     </ScrollView>

</LinearLayout>
```

Thanks !!!

Comment: You could just override the whole dialog layout.

Comment: @user3249477: How do I go about doing this?

Comment: Is the ScrollView you've added here supposed to be the content below the divider?

Comment: @user3249477: thanks for reply. Yeah it is the content below the divider

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I implemented your ScrollView into my own dialog design. Changed a few things but I think it should still properly imitate the default android dialog.

```
<LinearLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/dialog"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical">
    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/title"
        android:gravity="center_vertical"
        android:textColor="#28B0DF"
        android:layout_marginLeft="20dp"
        android:layout_marginRight="20dp"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="35dp"
        android:textSize="20sp"
        android:singleLine="true"
        android:ellipsize="marquee"
        android:marqueeRepeatLimit="marquee_forever"
        android:scrollHorizontally="true"
        android:focusable="true"
        android:focusableInTouchMode="true"/>

    <View
        android:id="@+id/divider"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="2dp"
        android:background="#28B0DF"/>

    <ScrollView
        android:id="@+id/sv_finccalctr_infolayout"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content">

        <LinearLayout android:id="@+id/ll_sv_finccalctr_infolayout"
                      android:orientation="vertical"
                      android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                      android:layout_height="wrap_content">
            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/tv_finccalctr_info"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"/>
        </LinearLayout>
    </ScrollView>
</LinearLayout>
```

To use this layout just set it to your dialog:

```
dialog.setContentView(R.layout.dialog_layout);
```

This can be done in `onCreateView` or perhaps at `onCreateDialog`.